# How to connect to mailbox using Imap/imaps in Azure?

Tags: java, azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-marketplace

I have mailbox server access via Java Code using Basic Authentication and is public. (Fetching mail and attachment and sending data to database)

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("mail.imaps.host", host);
properties.put("mail.imaps.port", port);
properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.port", String.valueOf(port));
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect(userName, password); <-----
```

Need to migrate this flow.

Not able to find any Connector related to IMAP/POP3 in Azure Logic Apps. Not sure how to connect to mailbox server in Azure.

Found following which says to add POP3 Connector.

https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-logic/app-service-logic-connector-pop3.md

But i am not able to find generic connector in marketplace.
[image]

Can anyone suggest how to fix this or can i use some other Azure Service?

Comment: You could always write an Azure Function.